# List messages in channel of Guild a user is member of

Tags: discord

I'm currently trying to list the messages in a channel, using the `guilds/${guild.id}/channels` endpoint.

I'm using a Bearer token the user has authorized via OAuth2, so I'm expecting the token to provide permissions to read a guilds channel, given the user is a member of that guild.

Currently, I can get a list the Guilds that a user is a member of via the `/users/@me/guilds` api endpoint. And from the resulting list of guilds,  I'm using the guild `id` field to make the request to `guilds/${guild.id}/channels` which always results in a `401: Unauthorized` response.

Perhaps my assumptions are incorrect? Thanks.

Comment: It seems that as of now Discord is only providing members with limited Guild information. No access to further guild information = list of channels.